# How to build a dynamic html form remote CSV

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am trying to build a form to display live solar energy generation data. The data can be retrieved using the below jsp string.

```
http://pvoutput.org/service/r2/getstatistic.jsp?key=customer-key&sid=customer-id
```

The output from that jsp is a comma delimited string similar to below:

```
5379600,49505,112075,0,216496,2.802,48,20100830,20151216,5.412,20151215
```

The first value is energy generated, second is energy exported and so on...
I need to split these values and display on a custom designed HTML form.

I have reasonable HTML knowledge, but very little javascript or any other programming language knowledge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the `.split` method to split that string into an array: `var arr = output.split(',');`

Comment: by the way, this has nothing to do with JSP. the output format is simple comma separated values (short CSV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the CSV using ajax like this (requires jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
  url: "http://pvoutput.org/service/r2/getstatistic.jsp?key=customer-key&sid=customer-id",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function(csv) {
    // comma separated values can be converted to an array using split
    var dataarray = csv.split(",")
    // populate your html with the single data elements
    $("#yourform first").html(dataarray[0])
    $("#yourform second").html(dataarray[1])
    // ...
  });
}
```

This waits until your HTML is done loading, then issues an AJAX request and on completion of the request it splits the resulting values just to populate your HTML with them. Instead of document.ready you could also do this logic on a button click or the like.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. You've been of great help.

Comment: I tried the code just like you had given. But there seems to be some problem retrieving the data. Here is the error i get in the browser console: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://pvoutput.org/service/r2/getstatistic.jsp?key=8e52743289b20833f825aeb30d88cb1695500bd0&sid=41213&_=1450272134692. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: Right. This is a security restriction enforced by browsers. You could download the data on your server (wget or curl) and load the file from the local server using AJAX then. If you have access to PHP or the like you could also simply inject the file into your HTML.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks again.

Comment: I took your suggestion and used PHP to get the values and populate the input fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using php:

```
<?php
  $jsonurl = "http://pvoutput.org/service/r2/getstatistic.jsp?key=cust-key&sid=cust-id";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $jsonurl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if( !$result ) {
   die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  $myArray = explode(',', $result);
?>
```

Use the values from the array to populate the input fields like:

```
<input type="text" id="energygen" value="<?php echo $myArray[0];?>">
```